# Cohorting, is it a word? if not what should I use instead

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

In this context, I'm trying to express that Seamus accidentally was *frolicking* with the enemy.
I guess a better way to say it is *unintentionally interacting.*

> Domá turned to Seamus, “So let me get this straight. On your first day
> back in Ireland — you got caught by Vikings — lost Josie and Bally— and
> almost got yourself killed. Not to mention *cohorting* with both of my
> enemies and their conjurer. Does that sum it up?”

Comment: Are you thinking of _consorting_? Also, can one frolic unintentionally?

Comment: The OED thinks that *cohort* is obsolete as a verb, providing their most recent citation from the 16th century : **“a1572**   J. Knox *Hist. Reformation Scotl. in Wks.* (1846) I. 453   The Lard of Tullybarne and uther Noble men, who cohorted thame to quyetness.”

Comment: I think you want *unwittingly*, as in Seamus didn't realize who they were. And in the second sentence *Not to mention* can be swapped with *To say nothing of* to better accommodate the -ing verb.

Comment: Or maybe ***cavorting***?

Comment: @KateBunting, you are absolutely correct,[as I slam my hand to my forehead.]

Comment: Classic malapropism. Could be upgraded to an eggcorn if you think of them as an intimate cohort of four.

Answer (score 1):

> Seamus was accidentally fraternizing with the enemy.

**fraternize**

> To associate on close terms with members of a hostile group especially
> when contrary to military orders
>
> *were ordered not to fraternize with
> the enemy* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fraternize)

> Associate or form a friendship with someone, especially when one is
> not supposed to. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/fraternize)

---

> The upper-class girl who decides to **fraternize** with Western men even
> on a platonic basis can expert her family to severely criticize her
> and eventually reject her altogether if she persists. [Boye De Mente;
> *Women of the Orient*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Women_of_the_Orient/eIzQAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=even%20being%20seen%20talking%20was%20fraternizing&pg=PT64&printsec=frontcover)